# How to return from Scala method with generics

Tags: scala

I have two trait

```
trait TResponseData extends Serializable {} //all response data
trait TRequestData extends Serializable {} //all request
```

Now I have *Response* class, which contains data and request

```
case class Response[A <: TResponseData, B <: TRequestData](data: A, request: B = null){}
```

While instance of case class *Response* must have data, request is not mandatory. So I declared its default to null in case class constructor. From Scala console, I am able to create its instance like

```
Response(null, null)
Response(null)
```

To generate instance of *Response*, I have created helper method:

```
def generateResponse[A <: TResponseData, B <: TRequestData] (data: A, request: B, passRequestInResponse: Boolean): Response[A, B] = {
    if (passRequestInResponse) 
        return Response(data, request)
    return Response(data, null)
}
```

Based on boolean *passRequestInResponse*, I am setting request in Response. 
On compiling same, I am getting follow error:

```
error: type mismatch;
 found   : Null(null)
 required: B
           return Response(data, null)
```

How can I achieve same (making request optional in *generateResponse* method)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `null` is a bad idea (as is `return`) so it is better to use `Option`:

```
trait TResponseData extends Serializable //all response data
trait TRequestData extends Serializable //all request

case class Response[A <: TResponseData, B <: TRequestData](data: A, request: Option[B]=None)

def generateResponse[A <: TResponseData, B <: TRequestData] (data: A, request: B, passRequestInResponse: Boolean): Response[A, B] =
  if (passRequestInResponse) {
    Response(data, Some(request))
  } else {
    Response(data)
  }
```

You can also do some `Option` magic like this:

```
def generateResponse[A <: TResponseData, B <: TRequestData] (data: A, request: B, passRequestInResponse: Boolean): Response[A, B] =
  Response(
    data,
    Some(request).filter(_ => passRequestInResponse)
  )
```

The advantage of this formulation is that it will work if `request` is `null`, and will treat this case as if `passRequestInResponse` was `false`

#### Update

As noted by @jwvh it is not clear that the `generateResponse` function is useful because you can just call `Response(data, Some(request))` or `Response(data)` as needed. If you don't like that `Some` in the first version, then create a class object with a custom `apply` method:

```
object Response {
  def apply[A <: TResponseData, B <: TRequestData](data: A, request: B): Response[A, B]
    = Response(data, Option(request))
}
```

Then you can just use `Response(data, request)`. This will work correctly if `request` is `null`.

Answer (score 2):

You can either modify the `generateResponse()` return type...

```
def generateResponse[A <: TResponseData, B <: TRequestData] (data: A
                                                            ,request: B
                                                            ,passRequestInResponse: Boolean
                                                            ): Response[A, _] = 
  if (passRequestInResponse) Response(data, request)
  else                       Response(data, null)
```

... or you can cast the `null` to the required type.

```
def generateResponse[A <: TResponseData, B <: TRequestData] (data: A
                                                            ,request: B
                                                            ,passRequestInResponse: Boolean
                                                            ): Response[A, B] = 
  if (passRequestInResponse) Response(data, request)
  else                       Response(data, null.asInstanceOf[B])
```

(But don't use `return`. It's not idiomatic Scala.)

In general, I don't really see why you need `generateResponse()` at all. The `Response` constructor will still either have a `B` or it won't, so it *should* be an `Option[B]` that defaults to `None`. (Idiomatic Scala avoids `null`.)

Comment: thanks for reply. I will be using generateResponse because I am doing some more operation in it.

Answer (score 1):

The reason for the error is that all types in Scala have a bottom type of Nothing. Nothing cannot accept the "null" value and therefore the type definition is problematic as B can be Nothing.

To solve this you can add a lower bound:

```
 def generateResponse[A <: TResponseData, B >: Null <: TRequestData ] (data: A, request: B,
                                                           passRequestInResponse: Boolean): Response[A, B] = {
```

this will mean that Nothing is an illegal type for B as the minimum allowed in Null.

The use of Option[B] is probably a better idea and should be used in this case in term of good design, however, in more generic cases there are situations where lower bound would be better.

P.S. you shouldn't be using return. As you can see in other answers you can do:

```
if (passRequestInResponse) {
  Response(data, Some(request))
} else {
  Response(data)
}
```

as this will give the value. Return is actually a control flow breaking (it is implemented with an exception) and can have unintended consequences. See for example https://blog.knoldus.com/scala-best-practices-say-no-to-return/